# Command blocks: Keep executing chain if block fails

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to keep running a command block chain if a command in one of the commands "fails"?

Example: If I use `setblock` on a position that already contains the specified type of block the whole chain stops executing because of the `Could not set the block` error.

I can use `destroy` at the end of `setblock` commands, but this results in dropping the destroyed item which causes other issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you may be mistaken with the premise of your question.

A chain of command blocks will always continue and execute the full chain, unless said chain command blocks are set to the “Conditional” setting, highlighted below:

[image: Conditional setting in chain command blocks]

When any command block set to this setting is triggered, it will check the command block on the side directly *opposite* its arrow <sup>(not necessarily the command block that points at it)</sup>, and it will only run itself if *that* command block's previous output was success.

But if *that* command block's previous output was a fail, then the conditional command block will not run its own command. **However,** if it is a *chain* conditional command block, it will *still continue* to propogate the chain signal down the line of chain command blocks, and any *unconditional* chain command blocks further down the line will still run.

Therefore, the most likely issue from the info you've provided is that your command blocks are set to “Conditional.” Setting the command blocks to unconditional will mean that they will always run when triggered, without caring about the previous output of any other command block.

Comment: I was indeed mistaken here. I should have questioned the `Conditional` setting but didn't think of it. Thank you!